# Angular SSR: Missing mat-expansion-panel animation

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ssr

I've added Angular/SSR (v17.1.2) by `ng add` schematic.
Everything started well.

I have a few mat-expansion-panels (wrapped in a mat-accordion), which are collapsed by default (as a "FAQ" section).
With using SSR I am trying to click on the header of the expansion-panel to expand it but nothing happens.

In my app config I am providing animations as the following:

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
...
```

What is missing do get this working?